# How to use ~/.XCompose in Qt/KDE Apps

Tags: kde, qt, xorg, input-method, konsole

I installed a very nice ~/.XCompose file (which I found on [github](https://github.com/kragen/xcompose/)). However, KDE apps at least do not use it unless I manually select XIM input mode on all the widgets.

Is there a way to specify this globally? Or at least to get it in konsole?

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the [edubuntu wiki](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ComposeKey)?
Please check whether "QT_IM_MODULE" and "GTK_IM_MODULE" are defined.